# Airflow tells me dag has run successfully while it has finished its tasks

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I'm using airflow to orchestrate an etl process and I have built the following task:

```
for sql_file in sql_files:
  t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id= sql_file + '_run',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=run_sql_from_file,
    op_kwargs={'filename': sql_file + '.sql',
               'connection': connection,
               'logger': logger
               },
    trigger_rule='all_done',
    dag=dag)
```

The sql files all have the same structure and are variations on this script:

```
    delete from databaseY.tableX;

    insert into databaseY.tableX
    select *
    from     databaseZ.tableW as bs
    inner join databaseW.tableY as cd on bs.id_camp = cd.id_camp
```

First the records of the datatable are deleted and then new records get inserted.

When I run this task from an airflow dag I get no errors whatsoever, in fact Airflow tells me that all the tasks have been run successfully. Unfortunately, when the dag is finished some of the datatables are empty. I think this is caused by the fact that the task deletes the data from the datatable, but never finishes inserting the new data. I think airflow times out, but I don't know where I can make sure this doesn't happen.

**Question:** How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run this python function as async or sync or check db operation status in run_sql_from_file? If you run it as async, maybe it  doesn't return status.  I always write operators to check db operation status in this kind of situation.